# regex replacing url with link and adding specific rel

Tags: php, regex

The code below is checking text from a string for any URLs and converting them to clickable links.

I'm trying to get it so that if there is a link to an image, it adds rel="image" in the < a> tag. If there is a youtube video, it adds rel="youtube" to the < a> tag.

It works fine if there is just one link in the string. When there are more than one, all links get the rel of whatever the last link is.

```
$text = "http://site.com a site www.anothersite.com/ http://imgur.com/image.png http://youtu.be/UyxqmghxS6M here is another site";

$linkstring = preg_replace('/(http|ftp)?+(s)?:?(\/\/)?+(www.)?((\w|\.)+)+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU|be|info|co)+(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '<a rel="iframe" href="\0">\0</a>', $text ); 
if(preg_match('/((http:\/\/)?(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:[a-z]{2,3}\.)?youtube\.com\/v\/)([\w-]{11}).*|http:\/\/(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:[a-z]{2,3}\.)?youtube\.com\/watch(?:\?|#\!)v=)([\w-]{11}).*)/i', $linkstring, $vresult)) {
    $pattern = "/(http|ftp)?+(s)?:?(\/\/)?+(www.)?((\w|\.)+)+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU|be|info|co)+(\/)?(\S+)?/i";
    $replacement = '<a rel="youtube" href="\0">\0</a>';
    $text2 = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
    $type= 'youtube';
} elseif(preg_match('/(http(s?):)?|([\/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg|bmp)/i', $linkstring, $vresult)) {
    $pattern = "/(http|ftp)?+(s)?:?(\/\/)?+(www.)?((\w|\.)+)+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU|be|info|co)+(\/)?(\S+)?/i";
    $replacement = '<a rel="image" href="\0">\0</a>';
    $text2 = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
    $type= 'image';
} else {
    $type = 'none';
}
echo $text, "<br />";
echo $text2, "<br />";
echo $linkstring, "<br />";
echo $type, "<br />";
```

I have tried changing $pattern so that it matches the same regex as the youtube or image link but it ends up creating a link for the whole text after the URL.

Example:

```
$text = "http://site.com a site www.anothersite.com/ http://imgur.com/image.png http://youtu.be/UyxqmghxS6M here is another site";

$linkstring = preg_replace('/(http|ftp)?+(s)?:?(\/\/)?+(www.)?((\w|\.)+)+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU|be|info|co)+(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '<a rel="iframe" href="\0">\0</a>', $text ); 
if(preg_match('/((http:\/\/)?(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:[a-z]{2,3}\.)?youtube\.com\/v\/)([\w-]{11}).*|http:\/\/(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:[a-z]{2,3}\.)?youtube\.com\/watch(?:\?|#\!)v=)([\w-]{11}).*)/i', $linkstring, $vresult)) {
    $pattern = "/((http:\/\/)?(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:[a-z]{2,3}\.)?youtube\.com\/v\/)([\w-]{11}).*|http:\/\/(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:[a-z]{2,3}\.)?youtube\.com\/watch(?:\?|#\!)v=)([\w-]{11}).*)/i";
    $replacement = '<a rel="youtube" href="\0">\0</a>';
    $text2 = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
    $type= 'youtube';
} else {
    $type = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot get your RegExes to work, to see exactly what your output looks like (it might if help if you posted the resulting strings instead of just describing them).

However, what you do is the following. In your first snippet in your if-statement you check whether the string contains a youtube link or an image link. But then you do not use the information at all but just use preg_replace on the whole initial string again. Which of course replaces all links and not just the one you found with preg_match before (because the call is completely unrelated).

So your second approach is actually better. Although, I do not think that you need the if-clause at all in that case, because only string parts will be replaced that match the same pattern. The reason why you get the full string after the link is something called greediness in RegExes. And it occurs because you end the two possible youtube patterns with `.*`. This could of cause just match the remaining part of the URL, but it will always take in as much as it can. And because `.` matches any character, that is the rest of the string. So first of all, you need to tell the regex where to stop taking characters into account. For example, you could say URLs end at a space or quotation marks. So instead of

```
(youtubepattern1).*|(youtubepattern2).*
```

you could try

```
((youtubepattern1|youtubepattern2).*)["\s]
```

But now greediness is still an issue, if there is more than the one quotation mark right after the URL or further whitespace later in the string (because then it will include everything until the last whitespace or quotation mark). (In PHP's regex methods) to tell the interpreter to treat .* ungreedily, add a question mark:

```
((youtubepattern1|youtubepattern2).*?)["\s]
```

Also, you will probably need to change your replacement from using `\0` to using `\1` now (because \0 will include the whitespace or quotation mark that ends the URL).